# Extension of Hopf Fibrations

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, fiber-bundles, octonions, hopf-fibration

The only hopf fibrations that exist are the first three listed here.

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
S^3 @>S^1>> S^2
\end{CD}

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
S^7 @>S^3>> S^4
\end{CD}

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
S^{15} @>S^7>> S^8
\end{CD}

For  a general case of SU(n) the fibrations can be written as such :
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
S^{2n^2-1} @>S^{2n-1}>> S^{2n[n-1]}
\end{CD}

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
S^{2n^3-1} @>S^{2n^2-1}>> S^{2n^2[n-1]}
\end{CD}
For the case of n = 3,These are fibrations that should theoretically exist. Is there a map that can be written for this case (somethink akin to complex numbers,quaternions and octonions) ?
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
S^{17} @>S^5>> S^{12}
\end{CD}

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
S^{53} @>S^{17}>> S^{36}
\end{CD}

Comment: As you've just stated in the beginning of your question, these fibrations don't exist: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1295852/when-is-there-a-submersion-from-a-sphere-into-a-sphere

Comment: Apologies if my comments appear somewhat uninformed.My knowledge regarding mathematics in limited since i work in physics. As far as i know, the existence of the hopf fibrations that do exist is related to the fact that only four normed division algebra exist comprising real numbers, real numbers,complex numbers,quaternions and octonions. Although a 16 dimensional algebra ( Sedenion ) does exist but but due lack of group structure,fails to be a normed division algebra.Cayley-dickson construction can yield 32 dim algebra and even higher dimensional algebras.

Comment: Its due to this reason that my focus is not on the $\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
S^{31} @>S^{15}>> S^{16}
\end{CD} but rather on SU(3) or for that matter SU(n) n >3 where a structure similiar to complex numbers, quaternions and octonions could be found. The only reason i think such a structure could be found is due to the symmetry of Fibration diagram of SU (n).

Comment: All of that is true but nevertheless you've already listed all of the possible fibrations with base and total space a sphere, and there aren't any others.