# There is no smooth submersion from $S^2$ to $S^1$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Show that there is no smooth submersion from $S^2$ to $S^1$. I know of one algebraic topology proof which I think is not the shortest one. That submersion is an open map should be a useful fact in obtaining a nicer proof. Any ideas?

Comment: The immediate proof that comes to mind lifts such a map to the real numbers, and shows that submersivity is impossible in the presence of a maximum. It's short, did you have this in mind or something else?

Comment: Another approach to showing that there is no such submersion $f:S^2\to S^1$ would be to endow $S^2$ with its standard riemannian metric, and to pull the vector field $\frac\partial{\partial t}$ back to $S^2$ along the submersion, by selecting the only tangent vector at $m\in S^2$ that projects onto $\frac\partial{\partial t}$ while being orthogonal to $ker(d_mf)$. This contradicts the hairy ball theorem.

Comment: Thanks for your first solution, which is a nice one. I think such a lift is possible because because the induced map from $\pi_1(S^2)$ to $\pi_1(S^1)$ is injective. The solution in my mind is more or less similar to your second solution, but without mention of Riemannian metric and with  more algebraic topology favor.

Comment: $\pi_1(S^2)=0$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294161/existence-of-submersions-from-spheres-into-spheres answers your question in greater generality (there is no submersion $S^{2n} \to M$ where $M$ is a manifold of dimension $< 2n$). See also this: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/207589/when-is-there-a-submersion-from-a-sphere-into-a-sphere